# In angular2, advantage of using zone.run vs changeDetecotor.markForCheck()

Tags: angular

I am wondering what's the advantage or disadvantage of using one over other:

```
 constructor(private app:ApplicationRef, private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.ref.markForCheck();
    // OR
    this.ref.detectChanges()  
    // will do same thing?
 ...
```

vs

```
zone.run

(() => doSomething())
    ...
```

vs

```
  app.tick();
```

they all essentially will mark the component for checking and updates / redraw the UI.

I know `app.tick()` will do it for the entire app, but in my tests it didn't actually force the UI to update.

`zone.run` and `markforCheck` both force the UI to update on the next zone cycle check, so why use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run code that only affects the current component, like

```
someServiceThatRunsOutsideZone.getData()
.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.ref.markForCheck();
});
```

`this.ref.markForCheck()` is just fine.

If you do for example `this.router.navigateXxx(...)` outside Angulars zone then it's hard to know if `this.ref.markForCheck()` will cover all elements that might get their state changed by this rather complex operation.

Also if `this.router.navigateXxx(...)` invokes some async calls, your `markForCheck` will be run before these async calls are completed and will not invoke change detection at the end as it is probably necessary.

With

```
this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigateXxx(...))
```

it doesn't matter because `this.router.navigateXxx()` and all code that is invoked by that call (sync and async) will run inside Angulars zone and use its patched API.

I don't know about the exact difference between `app.tick` and `markForCheck` but `app.tick` also does have the disadvantage explained above for `markForCheck`

Comment: got it... that makes sense, this.zone.run is more powerful as you have  future operations within the zone to be detected as well... got it, tx as always! – born2net 20 mins ago