# What are the implications of bootstrapping multiple components

Tags: angular

I can do the following:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, BComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, BComponent] <---------- here two components
})
```

and it'll create two html tags:

```
<my-app ng-version="2.4.5" _nghost-lii-0=""><h1 _ngcontent-lii-0="">Hello Angular</h1></my-app>
<b-app ng-version="2.4.5" _nghost-lii-0=""><h1 _ngcontent-lii-0="">Hello Angular</h1></b-app>
```

I'm wondering what are the implications of such setup?
Am I just going to have two trees of components with a single injector or they will act as two different applications? Any other things I haven't thought about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I just going to have two trees of components with a single injector

Yes, you will have two **independent** root trees. They will be registered under `ApplicationRef.views` and when `ApplicationRef.tick()` function will be called Angular will run change detection for both trees. It will be single application and they will share the injector defined for the `AppModule`.

Comment: Can you point some case where this approach needed? I mean using more than one root components in bootstrap? #Justasking

Comment: @PardeepJain, CDK portals would be a good example, i.e. rendering Angular components tree outside of Angular components)