# Why "bootstrap" key in @NgModule is an array?

Tags: angular

As per my knowledge, there can be only one entry point of an application. As shown in the code snippet given below we are passing an array in the bootstrap key which decide the entry point of the application.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MyComboboxComponent, 
                    CollapsibleDirective, CustomCurrencyPipe],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [UserService, LessonsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {

}
```

P.S: I am learning Angular 2 and the question may sound silly :)

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass as many bootstrap components as you want. You will simply end up with several independent components trees:

```
bootstrap: [AComponent, BComponent]

        RootModuleInjector
                |
                |
       ApplicationRef.views
       /                   \
      /                     \
   AComponent              BComponent
```

Also see [What are the implications of bootstrapping multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030969/what-are-the-implications-of-bootstrapping-multiple-components/45391130#45391130)

When running change detection Angular will run change detection for each tree separately:

```
class ApplicationRef {
   tick(): void {
    ...
    try {
      this._runningTick = true;
      // here this._views.length equals to 2
      this._views.forEach((view) => view.detectChanges());
```

You can even add new root component to the `ApplicationRef` manually if you want to:

```
const componentRef = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeComponent)
applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

        RootModuleInjector
                |
                |
       ApplicationRef.views
       /        |           \
      /         |            \
AComponent  SomeComponent   BComponent
```

If you need to share some data between the root components, you can define a provider on the root module which will be used to create a RootModuleInjector:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [ServiceSharedBetweenRootComponents]
}
export class AppModule {}
```

And then you'll be able to inject it into every root component:

```
export class AComponent {
    constructor(service: ServiceSharedBetweenRootComponents)
```

Comment: can two or more `independent trees with a single injector` communicate? How?

Comment: just define a service on the root module and inject it into each component

Comment: as shown in your diagram `AComponent` and `BComponent`. which one is the root module? do you mean to inject service at @NGModule level in providers?

Comment: In your recent edit, you made `SomeComponent` a root component and in the diagram you shown it as a sibling of A and B component... why?

Comment: I don't show it as a sibling. What makes you say so?

Comment: you said `You can even add new root component to the ApplicationRef manually if you want to` and made `SomeComponent` a root component manually. Then in diagram, you shown `ApplicationRef.views` as child of `RootModuleInjector` and `ACompnent`, `BCompnent` & `SomeComponent` as children of `ApplicationRef.views`. Please forgive my ignorance. Sometimes simple things are hardest to understand

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I've shown) what confuses you?

Comment: if `ACompnent, BCompnent & SomeComponent` are children of `ApplicationRef.views` then is `SomeComponent` not a sibling of `A` and `B`?

Comment: Right, sorry, I got confused. Yes, it's a sibling. Every root component is a sibling of the other root components

Comment: Oops!! Now I am too confused... How a `root` component can be a sibling as if I inject any service in root component then it will be shared with all the sub component down the tree... can you make your answer more elaboratetive for the forthcoming visiters :)

Comment: @VikasBansal "_if I inject any service in root component_" not the root component, the root **module**. The providers in the root module (the same module that you bootstrap the components) are shared across the app

Comment: Many thanks for your time and the amazing explanation. It is good to know these deep things. :)

Comment: @Maximus what is the use of putting multiple components in `bootstrap` ? still it take only First component like `bootstrap: [Acomponent, Bcomponent]` in `index.html` `<Bcomponentselector>loading..</Bcomponentselector>`  throws `Acomponentselector did not match any elements` In such case what is the purpose of mentioning multiple components.

Comment: @k11k2, yes, but you can have all html elements  for all bootstrap components inside the `index.html`, right?

Comment: what is the main purpose/scenario we'll come across mentioning multiple components in bootstrap @Maximus

Comment: @k11k2, I haven't come across the need to do that yet

Comment: @Maxim Koretskyi I am tunning my angular application. is there any performance gain if multiple bootstrapped component in nested tree.

Answer (score 4):

> there can be only one entry point of an application

No. You can instantiate multiple components as entry points in your application.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566919/5706293

Here is an example of how we can communicate between root components

- [Changing shared data between root modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686305/changing-shared-data-between-root-modules)