# Angular Change Detection on a route change

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, routes, angular2-changedetection

I have read some good articles on `Change Detection` in Angular and established somewhat good understanding of what it is and how it works. But every article I have read till now only focuses on `Change Detection` when some event happens on the component or when some `input` property changes etc. I haven't found any article yet which focuses on what happens when a `route` changes? How `Change Detection` works in that scenario? Also, does Angular pushes all HTML/DOM updates at once to the browser or does it keep feeding the browser constantly as soon as it finds any DOM update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Routing doesn't trigger change detection. The only thing that it does specific to change detection is [marking for check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396740/2545680) the router-outlet component being activated:

```
@Directive({selector: 'router-outlet', exportAs: 'outlet'})
export class RouterOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    ...
    activateWith(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver|null) {
        ...
        // Calling `markForCheck` to make sure we will run the change detection when the
        // `RouterOutlet` is inside a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` component.
        this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
        this.activateEvents.emit(this.activated.instance);
    }
```

Router is navigated by some event UI or other (setTimeout, XHR) etc. that is intercepted by NgZone and once the code finished executing change detection process kicks in.

> Also, does Angular pushes all HTML/DOM updates at once to the browser
>   or does it keep feeding the browser constantly as soon as it finds any
>   DOM update?

It updates DOM element by element as it progress through each component. For the most comprehensive explanation of change detection read all the articles mentioned in:

- [These 5 articles will make you an Angular Change Detection expert](https://blog.angularindepth.com/these-5-articles-will-make-you-an-angular-change-detection-expert-ed530d28930)

Comment: Thanks for commenting and explaining things. I have always enjoyed reading your articles and even though I have read most of them (mentioned in the article), I will read them again from another perspective. Thanks.

Comment: @ImranLatif, glad you found them helpful. You can also mark my answer as accepted if it helped. Good luck!