# How do I let angular know a custom window event has been fired and requires update checking

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using a [third-party library](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/get-started#load_the_javascript_client_library) that requires me to implement my own event listener. This is done by implementing `window.onGoogleYoloLoad = function() { ... }`. I tried to implement it like this in my user service file:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public userCredentials = new EventEmitter<Credentials>();
    constructor(){
        window.onGoogleYoloLoad = function(credentials){
            this.userCredentials.emit(credentials);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I subscribed to the event. The subscribers do get notified, but the view does not get updated. It's like angular doesn't know the event happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is running outside the Angular zone. Move the callback to a component and call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
    public userCredentials = new EventEmitter<Credentials>();
    constructor(
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private userService: UserService
    ){
        window.onGoogleYoloLoad = function(credentials){
            this.userService.userCredentials.emit(credentials);
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Re-entering the Angular zone is another option: [What's the difference between markForCheck() and detectChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges)

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public userCredentials = new EventEmitter<Credentials>();
    constructor(private zone: NgZone){
        window.onGoogleYoloLoad = function(credentials){
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.userCredentials.emit(credentials);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's because you can't inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into a service. Can you move the code to a component?