# Table rendering issue with infinite scroll - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm building a table with infinite scroll option. The initial load is going fine but when the next batch of data is added to the table I'm facing some rendering issue (at least that is how I see it) 
I can workaround it by explicit fire `detectchanges()` but I'm having difficulty to understand why I need to.

[Stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-testing-inifinte-option-v2?embed=1&file=app/table-http-example.ts&view=preview)

On `line:70` of `table-http-example.ts` I have disabled the `detectchanges()` so that you can see the issue.

Anybody can help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your facing is that Angular can’t keep track of items in the Array and has no knowledge of which items have been removed or added.

The reason your getting rendering issues is because angular needs to re-render the whole array when there is a change because of my first point.

By using `detectChanges()`, your telling Angular to detect local changes and update the view, ref: [What's the difference between markForCheck() and detectChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges).

To solve this you can use `trackBy()` which helps Angular track your changes and stops your whole re-rendering problem, ref: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf.