# Angular onPush does not update child property from parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a child component that looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    {{text}}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() text = '';

  constructor(public host: ElementRef) { }
}
```

And a parent component that looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.child.text = 'hello';
    this.child.host.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.child.text = 'from click';
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

The first assign to the `text` property is working fine, but when I click the button and try to change the `text` property again nothing is happening.

That's confusing because from what I know:
1. The click event should trigger change detection and the text property is different so it should have been updated.
2. I explicitly called `detectChanges()` and this should check also the children from what I know.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but since `text` is an `@Input` property, Angular probably expects you to be passing this value from parent to child, rather than modifying it directly from the parent.

Comment: Don't think it's the problem, because the first call is working.

Comment: Yeah but the first run of change detection tends to be the edge case or exception to the rules, but let's see if someone can explain this in more depth.

Comment: The problem is that you are using mutability in your object reference. This does not trigger change detection in the child, when using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.
You need to use an immutable method to change your object, like:

this.child = {
 ...this.child,
 text: 'from click'
};

You can also remove 'constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }' and 'this.cdr.detectChanges();'
This is only required, when you need to trigger change detection, manually, which you don't need to do, with immutability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20611) reported on GitHub. It occurs when:

- The `OnPush` change detection strategy is used for the child component
- An input property of the child is changed directly in the parent component code instead of being data-bound in the parent component template

The explanation given by [AngularInDepth.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545680/angularindepth-com):

> The compiler doesn't have a way to generate necessary information for checking
>   the bindings since it can't find these bindings in the template.
>   OnPush is tightly bound to the input bindings. What's important is
>   that Angular checks the second part of the binding (prop in the
>   example below), not the first (i):
>
> ```
> <child [i]="prop">
> ```
>
> to determine whether the change detection should be run for the child
>   component. And it does so when checking parent component. If you don't
>   show the compiler what parent property should be used to update child
>   input binding, it can't generate necessary information used when
>   checking the parent. So inspecting @Input on child components isn't
>   enough. That's the mechanism of change detection and I don't see any
>   way it could be changed.

One workaround suggested by [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) in the discussion is to call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck` in the child component after setting the `text` property, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-xhwhji). As a matter of fact, it works without calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` in the parent component.

```
export class ChildComponent {

  private _text = '';

  @Input()
  get text() {
    return this._text;
  }
  set text(val) {
    if (this._text !== val) {
      this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    }
    this._text = val;
  }

  constructor(public host: ElementRef, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to call markForCheck and not detectChanges?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396740/1009922) and at the other ones in the same question. My understanding is that change detection is triggered by the click event but the `text` property of the child is not included in it (because of the `OnPush` strategy) unless you call `markForCheck` explicitely.

Comment: You can also use @ViewChild(MyChildComponent) to resolve the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

write update method in child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    {{text}}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() text = '';

  constructor(public host: ElementRef, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  update(): void{
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

call that method in parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.child.text = 'hello';
    this.child.host.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.child.text = 'from click';
      this.child.update();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using **mutability** in your object reference. This does not trigger change detection in the child, when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

You need to use an **immutable** method to change your object, like:

```
this.child = { ...this.child, text: 'from click' };
```

You can also remove `constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }` and `this.cdr.detectChanges();`
This is only required, when you need to trigger change detection, manually, which you don't need to do, with immutability.