# Angular why we need markForCheck when detectChanges also works

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am reading [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#observables) article which has a section on when to use `markForChange()`.

In his example he has the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cart-badge',
  template: '{{counter}}',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CartBadgeComponent {

  @Input() addItemStream;

  counter = 0;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addItemStream.subscribe(() => {
      this.counter++;
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    });
  }
}
```

And he uses the `markForCheck()` method in order to update the view. The thing that I don't understand is that why we need to use `markForCheck()` here when a call to `detectChanges()` **is also updating the view**?

I read the answer on StackOverflow for the question - [What's the difference between markForCheck() and detectChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges)

But it does not meet the example above. So, why don't call `detectChanges()` instead `markForCheck()`?

Comment: how does it not meet the example above? the answer you linked states that markForChanges is commonly used when you are working with OnPush Strategy, which is what is done here. In this specific case there is not difference between the two. However, while calling markForCheck for example twice within one iteration, will lead to one changeDetection cycle, calling detectChanges twice would cause two of them.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example, please?

Comment: @PatrickKelleter but lets say this component has multiple ancestors wouldn't `markForCheck` cause change detection on all of the ancestors and if one of them don't utilize `OnPush` detection it would cause performance issues, right?

Answer (score 0):

`markForCheck` will info to the parent node (to the root) that the component wants to check for updating view. And children of the component may not be updated.

`detectChanges` will check to update the view of the component and for both it's children component. So this way will need more effort than `markForCheck`