# Angular 6 refresh array and ngFor in template

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I use angular 6 and I have a [ngbCarousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api) that I want to add photos with a click of a button.

I use `ngFor` to create the HTML of the carousel.

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let im of images; let i = index">
    <img [src]='im.link' >
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={{im.name}} >    
      <input type="text" value='description of img' >    
      <input type="text" value='copyright owners' >          
      <button type="button" (click)='deletepic(i)'>delete</button>   
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>

<button type="button" (click)='addpic()'>add</button> 
<button type="button" (click)='last()'>last</button>
```

The `images` array that contains JSON is this `images= [{'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=5','name':'first'},{'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=574','name':'second'},{'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=547','name':'third'}];` and when the `addpic` is clicked, another json is added in the array.

```
 addpic(){
    this.images.push({'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=7','name':'added one'});     
      this.last()        ;   
  }
```

Also it has to force carousel to show the last, newly added photo. According to the API I have to use the `select` to navigate to a slide by its id, and the id is of the pattern `ngb-slide-0`.

So, `last` contains

```
  last(){
    let slide = 'ngb-slide-'+String(this.images.length-1);    
    this.carousel.select(slide); 
  }
```

The last photo is normally added to the carousel

**The problem** is that the `last` will not work when called from the `addpic`. It never goes to the last photo, even if the photo is added. If I put the

```
let slide = 'ngb-slide-'+String(this.images.length-1);    
this.carousel.select(slide);
```

of `last` in the `addpic` will still not work. It always goes to the second to last photo (if I have 3 photos it always goes to the 3rd, after adding a 4th)

But this **will work** if I hit the last button or if I use the arrows in the carousel UI.

This makes me think that somehow the HTML or the array are not "refreshed" when the `last` is called in the typescript, but somehow the buttons refresh/create the HTML needed to show the right photo?

I dont know what it is, but I am almost certain now it has to do with html/typescript being refreshed. I think this is an angular issue and not a ngbCarousel issue. I dont know how to debug or proceed.

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After adding picture in array in addpic() method they take bit time to reflect in html as template so call last method in timeout like

```
addpic(){
    this.images.push({'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=7','name':'added one'});     
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.last();
    });
  }
```

Comment: So, it boils down to a JS event loop issue. `setTimeout` is a dirty hack and I love as with all dirty hacks :) The problem is that the first time is called I can see a flash of blank `div` with no image inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to force the `last` method being executed after the changes has been detected by Angular, as in Paresh Gamis's answer.

But I think you could also use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in this situation, it feels less "hacky". ([Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges), and related Q&A here : [What's the difference between markForCheck() and detectChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges) )

use it just before your `last` call.

I am not sure if it will work in your case (if you provide a StackBlitz minimal example, we could work on the details)

Comment: `setTimeout` is great but gives a flash of empty carousel sometimes. About `detectChanges` : sounds awesome but I am an angular newbie and I dont have a clue what to do. What is the logic? Detect if the HTML `ngb-carousel` is changed and then call the `last` ? Can you please elaborate more and I will set up a stockBling or whatever you kids call it these days. Just kidding, I am setting a StackBlitz

Comment: I am sorry, I dont have a clue with this is blank, I imported the ng-bootstrap, the `bootstrap.css` and the necessary imports in the component. "It works in my machine" . I try to figure out whats is wrong [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wcwcl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @selvin there are two errors which i can fix (and now I can see your example). First, there is an import line you need to delete in the component (MapcmsService), and you need to add ReactiveFormsModule in the imports of app.module.ts

Comment: Now I'm stuck, I can't add photos (it seems that stackblitz doesn't like picsum.photos ? Or is it my network corp that mess with HTTPS currently ?)

Comment: basically, I just wanted to try `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); this.last();` instead of  `setTimeout(() => {
        this.last();
    });`

Comment: I have some bad news.When you delete a photo and then add a new one, then I guess the `ngb-slide-XX` ids are getting messed up and I end up in the second-to-last photo again!!!! This is getting out of hand. Is there a way to just show the last photo? What frustrates me is that I have a simple array and I cannot force angular to just go to its end and somehow render what is inside. I cannot think of anything right now, if you have any advice,that would be great. Otherwise I dont know. I wll open an issue on `ng-bootstrap` I guess. I dont have time to build my own gallery...

Comment: Sorry for freaking out, there is a solution. I can have angular traverse the `ng-template ngbSlide` tag, get the last one, get its id and use this on the `this.carousel.select(actually_last_slide);` Working on it