# Angular variable is not updating when request if finished

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular10

I have my html file `game-page-details.component.html`:

```
<ngx-shimmer-loading *ngIf="!apkDto else appCover" [width]="'100%'" [height]="'100%'"></ngx-shimmer-loading>
        <ng-template #appCover>
            <img src="assets/media/image/slider-image/slider-1.png">
            there
        </ng-template>
```

and my typescript file `game-page-details.component.ts`

```
  apkDto: ApkDto = null;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gameId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('gameId');
    this.loadApkInfo(Number(this.gameId));
  }

  private loadApkInfo(apkId: Number) {
    // Get the information about the game
    const param = { id: Number(apkId)};
    this.searchApkController.getApkByIdUsingGET(param).subscribe(
        (apkDto) => {
          if(apkDto) {
            console.log(apkDto);
            this.apkDto = apkDto;
            
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          //TODO: if there is an error, we notify the cloudwatch, but show to user that there no notification
        });

  }
```

At the end of subscribe request, the apkDto variable is not updated in the front.
How could I subscribe the local variable apkDto (without creating external service) so when the request is finished, the variable is updated ?

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than subscribing (and also probably trigger change detection) manually, use `| async`.

Comment: @developer033 do you have an example ? i found many example but don't know which i have to choose

Comment: Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zfnjr7

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a semi-colon after your *ngIf="!apkDto;.." per instructions at https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description

Comment: i add it but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Based on [**developer033**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4911842/developer033)'s [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605033/angular-variable-is-not-updating-when-request-if-finished?#comment121246846_68605033) and [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605033/angular-variable-is-not-updating-when-request-if-finished?#comment121254036_68605033), I did something like this based on `async`:

```
  @Input()
  apkDto: ApkDto = null;
  apkDto$: Observable<ApkDto>;
 
 
  const param = { id: Number(apkId)};
  this.apkDto$ = this.searchApkController.getApkByIdUsingGET(param);
```

and the html file

```
<img *ngIf="apkDto$ | async as apkDto; else appCover" src="{{ apkDto.translatedMetadataList['EN'].coverDownloadUrl }}">

<ng-template #appCover>
  <ngx-shimmer-loading [width]="'100%'" [height]="'100%'"></ngx-shimmer-loading>
</ng-template>
<div class="banner_overlay">
  <img src="assets/media/image/game-page/overlay.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular may not update the view automatically (depending on [change detection strategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)). A way to ask Angular to render the view is to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57382013) explains it deeper.