# What is the right way to use changeDetection.markForCheck() in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection, change-detector-ref

I am using `markForCheck` to detect changes in my angular component (Which has `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`) and initially, I put the `markForCheck` at the start of the function and It was working for me then I realized it will make more sense to put that after all the function action is done.

In both the approach angular was detecting the changes if it is called initially or after the action is done.

So if someone can justify what will be the right way to use markForCheck?

```
functionName() { // It works at both places
  this.cd.markForCheck();
  //
  .... Some Code that needs markForCheck ....
  //
  this.cd.markForCheck();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to use this.cdr.markForCheck() after changed some data and component have property changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

becouse in this case component will not reload self html template
if some subchild components have OnPush - parent "markForCheck()" will redraw them too.
if changed data display in subcomponent without OnPush u can don't use "markForCheck()"

in my case compA have mat-table in html, so after reload items i call markForCheck() for redrawing mat-table

Answer (score 1):

You use `markForCheck()` to tell Angular to 'flag' changes that happened outside of the active change detection strategy.

When you are using the default change detection strategy, `markForCheck()` is not necessary and my guess is that is why it didn't matter where you originally had your `markForCheck()` call.

The correct place to call `markForCheck()` is inside a component with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` *after* you make changes that won't get picked up by the OnPush change detection.

Here is a more in-depth explanation that you might find helpful,
[What's the difference between markForCheck() and detectChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364386/whats-the-difference-between-markforcheck-and-detectchanges)

EDIT: I mistakenly said that markForCheck() triggers the change detection and that is incorrect. Thanks @Fatih Ersoy

Comment: Are you sure of that markForCheck() runs change detection?

Comment: how to use markForCheck()? Like, where and how to write that call to tat function (I guess it is a function).

Comment: this worked. I injected its class it as service.